# Reorder the contents of div and its elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am looking to reorder the contents of the div in a particular order. The contents inside of the div comes dynamically from CMS content. I have 2 paragraph elements that come from CMS, and one image inside of a div. Now my requirement is I want to show them in a particular order. I don't want to use flex display and give an order. Is there any other way I can achieve this?

Since it is a dynamic content, I am posting a sample markup of how it is going to look.

**Sample Code:**

These 2 div and its contents below are coming from CMS.

```
<div class="order-class">
<div>
<p> Some sample content </p>
</div>
<div>
<p> Some other sample content </p>
</div>
</div>
```

Here in my JSP I have another div with an image in it. Sample below

**Sample Code:**

```
<div class="koh-release-content-section">
<hst:html hippohtml="${pressRelease.content}" /> //This is the sample content mentioned above
<div class="koh-press-release-detail-image order-class">
<tag:imagePressRealeasetag image="${pressRelease.image}"/>
</div>
</div>
```

I am not able to figure out how to reorder these elements. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why is display flex with an order not an option?

Comment: Because, if you see the dynamic content from CMS will have a few more div's along with the 2 div's i specified here. When I do display flex with an order, then it will mess up the other contents. The problem is the content is dynamic

Comment: What order do you want to show them in?

Comment: order on flexbox, grid-area on grids, some sort of position absolute, or even some javascript to actually manipulate the order by removing the element and prepend in place might do it. But you need to be more specific about which elements do you want to re-position, and where to. Can't guess.

Comment: @sol - I want to swap div #2 from the dynamic content and the image inside the jsp.

Comment: @FacundoCorradini - So the div with content "Some sample content" stays as it is. The other div with content "Some other sample content" and the div with the image has to be swapped.

Comment: So... "some sample content >> some other sample content >> image" into  "some sample content >> image" >> some other sample content" ??

Comment: @FacundoCorradini - Thats right! That exactly what I need.

Comment: Any reason not to use flex?

Comment: @FacundoCorradini - The number of div's that come from CMS dynamically is not a static number. There can be any number of div's along with the 2 I mentioned here. If I do flex and give the order, then it will mess up the other contents.

Comment: It shouldn't. Setting the "some content" div to order: -2 and the image div to order -1 would leave all others where they belong

Comment: Please edit the question with some different examples of the html possible outputs.

Comment: @FacundoCorradini - That actually did the trick. But i had to set all the other contents expect some content to -1 for me to actually achieve this!